# Date comparison in coredata fetch request?

Tags: ios, core-data

In my application I am using coredata.One endDate field of type NSDate is there in my 'Job'table. I want to get all records from 'Job' having endDate less than the current date ?
Any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set a predicate like this in your fetch request:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"endDate < %@", [NSDate date]]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when I tried your code the app gets crsahed with exception '-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a727f0

Comment: This predicate is just copied from working code. Please share the full code of your fetch request and your entity description.

Comment: @Jeff: That probably means that your `endDate` attribute is stored as a *string*, and not as a *date*.

Comment: @Leijonien  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest        = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"endDate < '%@'",[NSDate date]]]];

Comment: 3 questions: Not sure if it's in issue, but why are you using single quotes '' in the predicate? (`'%@'` should be `%@`). And can you confirm your endDate is of type NSDate? And as far as i know the fetch request needs an entity (`fetchRequest setEntity:`).

Comment: Yes it iss of type NSDate.When I removed the single quotes Unable to parse the format string "endDate < 2013-11-18 20:07:37 +0000

Comment: Ah.. You should remove the `[NSString stingWithFormat:]` in your predicate. Just use the exact predicate i mentioned.

Comment: @Leijonien It's working when I changed [NSString stringWithFormat:@"endDate < %@",[NSDate date]] to @"endDate < %@", [NSDate date] I don't what is the difference :) Anyway Thanks

Comment: You'r welcome. The difference is: By using the `[NSString ..` in your predicate, you are passing a string to the predicate, not a format. The predicate is expecting a format.